# LINQ GroupBy, convert a one-to-one list to a one-to-many

Tags: .net, linq, grouping

This can be done in a million ways ...

Problem.
I have a list of servers which belongs to a country.

Countries have many servers, so its a 2 way navigation( I think its called )

Now I have a list of servers with there country set and want to group by country so I can get the opposite list.

List of countries with all there servers attached to the ICollection of the Country ( Servers )

```
var groupBy = list.GroupBy(x => x.Country, x => x, (c, s) => new {c, s});
foreach (var country in groupBy)
{
}
```

This will almost give me the result I want, but now I have 2 anon types.
C which is country and S which is the list of servers.

How can I attach the list of servers to the country object's Collection.

Classes look like this... simplified.

```
public class Server
{
    public short SID { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public byte CID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Server> Servers { get; set; }
}
```

I guess one could create a new Country with the information and then also put the list of servers in the constructor ... but that's kind of overkill I think.

Well ... this odd to be simple but I'm lost here.

### Update

I need to select all servers that satisfy some condition. That's why I have a list of servers with the country. Now I just need to invert the list. Can this be done the other way around ?

I'm using the Repository Pattern with EF 4 Code First.
IRepository
I only have the following methods available with a option to eager load a property:
Single, SingleOrDefault, Find and FindAll

There are no lazy load, they all return ICollection or a single T.

Comment: any reason why your list is a collection of servers? perhaps you can get the list as collection of countries in the first place

Comment: Well yes. I need to select all servers that satisfy some condition. Thats why I have a list of servers with the country. Now I just need to invert the list ... can this be done the other way around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you really just want to build up a Lookup from country to servers:

```
var lookup = servers.ToLookup(server => server.Country);
```

If that's *not* what you're looking for, please let me know how it doesn't do what you want :)

Admittedly there's no guarantee that each `Country` will have all the servers in the original list, and that sounds like it's that distinction which is really the problem.

If your `Server` already has the `Country` set, can you not assume that the data is already consistent? If not, shouldn't your `Server` *really* have a CID instead of a `Country` reference? Having a property which will *sometimes* be consistent with "this" object and sometimes not (i.e. whether `server.Country.Contains(server)` is guaranteed to return `true` or not) is ugly IMO.

EDIT: Okay, a possibly nicer alternative is:

```
var query = servers.GroupBy(server => server.Country.CID);
                   .Select(g => new Country { CID = g.Key,
                                              Servers = g.ToList() });
```

This is almost the same as fermaref's approach, but I'm *explicitly* using `Country.CID` to avoid two servers with *equivalent* countries not ending up in the same bucket due to potentially odd equality rules.

Comment: doesn't it ToLookup need at least 2 arguments? one for the key and one for the source?

Comment: @K Ivanov: The source is the "servers" part here - ToLookup is an extension method.

Comment: sorry, I met the element, not the source; or are we assuming the "list" have already the server-country association

Comment: Theres always a Country for a server. A country can have zero or more servers. I'm getting the list and wanted to convert it before handing over the model to the View.

Comment: @Syska: But will the Country already be populated with servers?

Comment: @K Ivanov: If you don't specify an element selector, the source element itself is used for the element in the lookup. It's equivalent to `servers.ToLookup(server => server.Country, server => server);`

Comment: that will work then; the only problem now is the lookup will not contain countries with no servers; those were not going to be in the original server list anyway by default

Comment: @K Ivanov: Indeed. But given a source of only "servers" we could never get such countries.

Comment: @jon Well, the Country will have an assision with one server that got selected when doing the first search. But theres no problem in overwriting that property.

Comment: @Syska: Okay, it sounds like it would be better to create a new Country from each result to be honest. Editing...

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have a list of servers with each country set and want to group by country so I can set the opposite list.

Linq is for querying and it has a functional mindset where you generate new instances instead of modifying existing instances.

If you want to modify instances, a foreach loop is superior:

```
List<Server> servers = GetServers();

foreach(Server server in servers)
{
  Country c = server.Country;
  c.Servers.Add(server);
}
```

If you must use Linq:

```
List<Server> servers = GetServers();

foreach(IGrouping<Country, Server> g in servers.GroupBy(s => s.Country))
{
  Country c = g.Key;
  c.Servers = g.ToList();
}
```

---

> Now I just need to invert the list.

```
ILookup<Country, Server> lookup = servers.ToLookup(s => s.Country);
List<Country> countries = lookup.Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
foreach(Country c in countries)
{
  c.Servers = lookup[c].ToList();
}
return countries;
```

Comment: Yes, now you mention it. I Just wanted to make sure I was not doing something overkill, if this was actually possible in a simple linq. But after reading all the answers they all go in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't guarantee that the `Country` object in each `Server` object already contains all the Servers, you can create a new `Country` object:

```
var groupBy = list.GroupBy(
                    x => x.Country, 
                    x => x, (c, s) => 
                                new Country 
                                {
                                  CID = c.CID, 
                                  Servers =  s.ToList()});
```

However, I'm not sure if that's what you want.

If you can guarantee that the `Country` object will always contain all `Servers`, you can could use the following:

```
var countries = list.SelectMany(s => s.Country).Distinct();
```

or, if your `Country` doesn't implement `IEquateable`:

```
var groupBy = list.GroupBy(x => x.Country).Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: Well ... the result is what I want. I just want to avoid creating the Country again and just attach the servers to the country. In the real object there are lots of other properties so it would be a bit longer list. I was just hoping that there were something obviously that I was missing.